# Sequence of functions defined on a compact domain pointwise bounded and pointwise equicontinuous

Tags: real-analysis, sequence-of-function, equicontinuity

This is problem 13 from page 264 of Pugh's *Real Mathematical Analysis*.
Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of functions $\mathbb{R}\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ such that if $K \subset \mathbb{R}$, $K$ compact, then the restricted sequence $(f_n|_K)$ is pointwise bounded and pointwise equicontinuous.

a) Does it follow that there is a subsequence $(f_n)$ that converges to a continuous limit function $\mathbb{R}\mapsto\mathbb{R}$?

b) What about uniform convergence?

I really don't know how to approach this problem. Hints or a solution would be appreciated.

Comment: Does the name Ascoli ring a bell?

Comment: Take a discontinuous function at one point (a constant function with a jump at one point works) and approximate it by continuous functions.

Comment: @DanielFischer doesn't that theorem only work for an equicontinuous sequence of functions?

Comment: We *have* an equicontinuous sequence. Note that on a compact set, every equicontinuous family is uniformly equicontinuous, although I'm not sure whether that fact is needed to prove the Ascoli-Bourbaki theorem.